# When writing RSpec tests with rails, what should go in the spec/requests folder vs spec/controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm fairly new to rails and trying to do things the "right" way by implementing tests from the get go.  Yesterday I used the scaffolding generator to create my first model/view/controller configuration.  While I've been told that you really shouldn't be using scaffolding, it was useful so that I could learn how Rails code is structured.

The one thing I noticed was that the automatically generated RSpec was mostly placed in the ***spec/controllers folder***.  However when I watched [this episode of Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara), I noticed that he used the

```
rails generate integration_test [test_name]
```

command which placed a single test file in the ***spec/requests folder***.  However all of his tests that he wrote interacted with the controllers.  What I'm trying to determine is the best practice for where to store these tests.

When should one store tests in the spec/requests folder and when should one store tests in the spec/controllers folder?  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually those are 2 types of tests. In the controller folder you should create tests to test the controller actions, in the request folder you should place tests to interact with views, wich will actually test all your application parts, and that's why it's named integration test.

Here are some articles about those two types of tests.

http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html

http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/24/testing-series-rspec-requests.html

Answer (score 0):

Controller specs test the invocation of a single controller action. Typically you won't render views (although you can turn this on), it's also pretty common to stub out a lot of model code. The only interaction you have with the code under test is to invoke a single controller action. You could think of these as unit tests for controllers.

Request specs on the other hand test the whole stack (routing, controllers, views, models etc). Rather than just invoking a single controller action you perform actions closer to what a user would do: visit a page, fill in a form, click a button. Often this will span multiple actions/controllers. For example you might write a request spec that takes a user through the process of adding a product to a cart and then going through the various steps involved in checking out.

You typically use capybara (i think you can still use webrat) to interact with the pages you generate. With a suitable capybara driver javascript on the page will also be executed so, for example, you could test that your client side javascript does the right thing with the json produced by your controller (although you might want to consider writing javascript specs if you have a lot of that)